# Fast get all subusers of specific node in django users table

Tags: python, django

I have django model:

```
class Profile(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='parent_user_for_profile')
```

How to create function which returns all the child users.

For example [See picture of hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na1vf.jpg)

```
For n12 - [n122, n1211б n121, dsf]
For n1 - [n12, n11, n122, n1211, n121, dsf]
For n2 - [n21, n212]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_children_of_user(parent):
    children = Profile.objects.filter(parent=parent).values_list('user', flat=True)
    for child in children:
        children += get_children_of_user(child)
    return children
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_children_of_user(parent_id):
    children = list(Profile.objects.filter(parent_id=parent_id).values_list('user_id', flat=True))
    for child in children:
        children += get_children_of_user(child)
    return list(children)
```

Comment: When providing answers on SO please also give an explanation for @OP to better understand what your code does and how it resolves the issue they were facing.